# get path of a result of query in php

Tags: php, sql, ftp

I am trying to get the direct path of the $result below:

```
$query="SELECT videoid from blabla";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$destination="ftp:/.../";
```

I am trying to get the direct path of the videoid which is in $result so i can send all the actual video files to an ftp.

So far  I have:

```
ftp_put ($connection,$destination,$result,FTP_ASCII);
```

When I run it it says that the source has to be a string or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$result` is not the field your are looking for, you have to fetch the data from the `$result`. Note the `mysql_fetch_assoc` call which pulls data out of the query result.

Here is an example from the [mysql_query documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

```
// Formulate Query
// This is the best way to perform an SQL query
// For more examples, see mysql_real_escape_string()
$query = sprintf("SELECT firstname, lastname, address, age FROM friends WHERE firstname='%s' AND lastname='%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string('fred'),
    mysql_real_escape_string('fox'));

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Check result
// This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}

// Use result
// Attempting to print $result won't allow access to information in the resource
// One of the mysql result functions must be used
// See also mysql_result(), mysql_fetch_array(), mysql_fetch_row(), etc.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['firstname'];
    echo $row['lastname'];
    echo $row['address'];
    echo $row['age'];
}

// Free the resources associated with the result set
// This is done automatically at the end of the script
mysql_free_result($result);
```

**You can therefore modify your code as follows:**

```
$query="SELECT videoid from blabla";
$result=mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    die($message);
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // loop through every videoid returned, ftp each individually
    ftp_put ($connection,$destination,$row['videoid'],FTP_ASCII);
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: @JJ, what is the purpose of `    mysql_real_escape_string('fred'),
    mysql_real_escape_string('fox'));` ? It makes no sense to me. Did you meanto replace `fred` with `$_POST['fred']`?

Comment: Fred is simply a sample first name given in the example. `mysql_real_escape_string` escapes certain characters in the input data to avoid problems such as "sql injection" (Google this). Also Google `mysql_real_escape_string` to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT videoid from blabla";
$result = mysql_query( $query );
$row = mysql_fetch_row( $result );
$videoid = $row[0]; // <== there is your videoid
$destination="ftp:/.../";
ftp_put( $connection, $destination, $videoid, FTP_ASCII );
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this:

To select one video:

```
// select all fields, not just the videoid
$query = "SELECT * FROM blabla WHERE videoid = 1"; // replace 1 with actual video id
// or only fields videoid and path
$query = "SELECT videoid, path FROM blabla WHERE videoid = 1"; // replace 1 with actual video id
$result = mysql_query( $query );
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
$path = $row[ 'path' ]; // presuming 'path' is the column name
/* do some ftp stuff */
```

To select all videos:

```
// select all fields, not just the videoid
$query = "SELECT * FROM blabla";
// or only fields videoid and path
$query = "SELECT videoid, path FROM blabla";
$result = mysql_query( $query );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
{
    $path = $row[ 'path' ]; // presuming 'path' is the column name
    /* do some ftp stuff per row */
}
```